# SQL Server 2008 filters query using checkbox

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 5 CheckBox and i want to filter data in gridview using checkbox by Star Rating,
I want that if user checked CheckBox1 then it show data of Star Raing 1 and user select CheckBox1 and CheckBox2 then it show data of Star Rating 1 and 2 also. I dont want to bind GridView Data using C# Code.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" Text="5" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" Text="4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" Text="3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" Text="2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Text="1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" ShowHeader="False" AllowPaging="True"
AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <telerik:RadRating ID="RadRating1" Runat="server" DbValue='<%# Bind("star_rating") %>'>
            </telerik:RadRating>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
<FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:travelconn %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Table_P tp inner join Table_D td ON tp.id= td.id where
td.star_rating in (@star1,@star2,@star3,@star4,@star5)">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CheckBox1" Name="star1" PropertyName="Checked" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CheckBox2" Name="star2" PropertyName="Checked" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CheckBox3" Name="star3" PropertyName="Checked" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CheckBox4" Name="star4" PropertyName="Checked" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CheckBox5" Name="star5" PropertyName="Checked" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am using ASP.Net C# SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a split function inside you database,

### Definition Of Split Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split]
    (
      @delimited NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @delimiter NVARCHAR(100)
    ) 
 RETURNS @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @xml XML
  SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@delimited,@delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'

  INSERT INTO @t(val)
  SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as item
  FROM  @xml.nodes('/t') as records(r)
  RETURN
END
```

### Stored Procedure

Then you need to create a stored procedure which will build sql query dynamically and use this split function to handle multiple comma deliminated list values from your drop down lists.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData
    @DropDown1  VARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @DropDown2  VARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @DropDown3  VARCHAR(1000) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

 SET @SQL = N' SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE 1 = 2 '
            + CASE WHEN @DropDown1 IS NOT NULL 
                THEN N' OR ColumnName1 IN (SELECT Val FROM dbo.split(@DropDown1 )) '
                    ELSE N'' END
            + CASE WHEN @DropDown2 IS NOT NULL 
                THEN N' OR ColumnName2 IN (SELECT Val FROM dbo.split(@DropDown2)) '
                    ELSE N'' END
            + CASE WHEN @DropDown3 IS NOT NULL 
                THEN N' OR ColumnName3 IN (SELECT Val FROM dbo.split(@DropDown3)) '
                    ELSE N'' END

  EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
                       ,N'@DropDown1 VARCHAR(1000), @DropDown2 VARCHAR(1000), @DropDown3 VARCHAR(1000)'
                       ,@DropDown1 
                       ,@DropDown2 
                       ,@DropDown3 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in a stored procedure and @star1,2, etc would be bit(1/0) variables..

```
SELECT * FROM Table_P tp inner join Table_D td ON tp.id= td.id where
(
 (td.star_rating =1 and @star1 = 1) 
or 
 (td.star_rating =2 and @star2 = 1) 
or 
 (td.star_rating =3 and @star3 = 1) 
or 
 (td.star_rating =4 and @star4 = 1) 
or 
 (td.star_rating =5 and @star5 = 1) 
)
```